# Change specific column value in a data file

Tags: shell, csv, awk, delimiter

Change specific column value in a data file

Ex : The file : input_file.out_RD has below data

```
6710|GB|LONDON|10
6700|GB|LONDON|20
6703|GB|LONDON|15
6876|GB|LONDON|60
```

Now want to double the column number 4 values , so output file should be 
: final_file.out_RD

```
6710|GB|LONDON|20
6700|GB|LONDON|40
6703|GB|LONDON|30
6876|GB|LONDON|120
```

Comment: IMHO there is a typo in your output, can't see values doubled, request you to please edit your question once.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 4):

You may want to say something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "|"} {$4 *= 2} 1' input_file.out_RD > final_file.out_RD
```

Result:

```
6710|GB|LONDON|20
6700|GB|LONDON|40
6703|GB|LONDON|30
6876|GB|LONDON|120
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO `awk` should be faster than shell solution, could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$NF=2 * $NF} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The below script helps to solve the issue :

```
#!/bin/sh

#input file from which a specific  column to be multiplied
my_file="/tmp/test/input_file.out_RD"

#multiplication factor value
multiplication_factor=2.00

while IFS= read -r line
do
        #read a line from input file and redirect to temporary file tmp_file.txt
        echo "$line" >tmp_file.txt

        #extract the forth column value from  temp_file.txt
        original_forth_col_value=`awk -F "|" '{print $4}' tmp_file.txt`

        #calculate the final forth column value
        final_forth_col_value=$(echo "$original_forth_col_value * $multiplication_factor" | bc )
        echo $final_forth_col_value

        #place the final forth column value in the output file --> final_file.out_RD
        awk -v fv=$final_forth_col_value  -F "|" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS}{$4=fv;print}' tmp_file.txt >> final_file.out_RD
done < "$my_file"
```

Comment: Could you please try once https://stackoverflow.com/a/61136443/5866580 solution too and let me know then if that helps you.